Firebase Notification Images not appearing at iOS client
I have set up my Ktor server to send Firebase Remote Notifications, everything works fine except Images not being attached with the Notification.
Here is my code:
AppDelegate.swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.Message_ID"

    //called when app launched
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil
    ) -> Bool {
        print("AppDelegate App launch called")
        //need to generate a debug token and print it to the console
        //search for "App Check debug token:" in the console to read the debug token
#if DEBUG
        let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
#endif

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )

        //just registers to received notifications, does not ask permission
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        //get a app check token
        AppCheck.appCheck().token(forcingRefresh: true) { token, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("App Check Error fetching token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let token = token  {
                print("App Check token \(String(describing: token.token)) created at \(token.expirationDate)")
            }
        }

        //register all the background tasks
        registerBackgroundTasks()
        return true
    }

    //called when registering for remote notifications is successful
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {
        print("AppDelegate didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called")
        //this method sets the apns token to the device token which is needed to identify the device
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    //called when firebase fcm token recieved
    func messaging(
        _ messaging: Messaging,
        didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?
    ) {
        print("AppDelegate Firebase registration token called: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

        let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: FirebaseMessaging.Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: dataDict
        )

        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        if let token = fcmToken {
            // Persist it on local storage
            persistViaUserDefaultsToLocalStorage(token, key: UserDefaultsFileKeys.notificationTokenPreferencesUDKey.rawValue)
            // Upload token to ktor
            uploadNotificationToken(token: token, appManager: AppSingleton.instance)
        }
    }

    //receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    //calld when app is in foreground and remote notification received
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification
    ) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("AppDelegate userNotificationCenter willPresent called userInfo is \(userInfo)")
        return [[.banner, .badge, .sound]]
    }


    //called when notification received
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler : @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        print("userNotificationCenter didReceive called")
        //get the user info
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        //post the notification for the device to show it
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Foundation.Notification.Name("didReceiveRemoteNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        completionHandler()
        print(userInfo)
    }


    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
    ) {
        // Handle incoming notifications
        print("App Delegate Received remote notification called: \(userInfo)")
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    //used to handle google sign in
    func scene(
        _ scene: UIScene,
        openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>
    ) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
    }

}

I have followed the steps here to create a Notification Service target.
NotificationService.swift
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

        print("NotificationService didReceive called") //This doesnt get printed when a new remote message is received in app foreground or background
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        guard let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent else { return }

        // Check if the notification payload contains an image URL
        guard let imageURLString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["image-url"] as? String,
              let imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString) else {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            return
        }

        // Download and process the image
        downloadAndAttachImage(from: imageURL, to: bestAttemptContent) { updatedContent in
            contentHandler(updatedContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    private func downloadAndAttachImage(from url: URL, to content: UNMutableNotificationContent, completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, _, error in
            guard let localURL = localURL, error == nil else {
                completion(content)
                return
            }

            do {
                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "image", url: localURL, options: nil)
                content.attachments = [attachment]
                completion(content)
            } catch {
                print("Error creating attachment: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(content)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

My Notification Service Extension has also been added the Push Notification Signing Capability in XCode.
Here is how I am setting up the notification at Ktor via Firebase admin:
val messageBuilder = Message.builder()
messageBuilder.setApnsConfig(
            ApnsConfig.builder()
                .setAps(
                    Aps.builder()
                        .setAlert(
                            ApsAlert.builder()
                                .setTitle(notification.heading?.removeSquareBrackets())
                                .setBody(notification.message.removeSquareBrackets())
                                .build()
                        )
                        .setSound("default")
                        .setBadge(1)
                        .setCategory(notification.notificationChannelId + notificationChannelIdVersion)
                        .setMutableContent(true)
                        .setContentAvailable(true)
                        .build()
                )
                .putHeader("apns-priority", "10")
                .setFcmOptions(
                    ApnsFcmOptions.builder()
                        .setImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jinarya-315507.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2Fzitykach_3d_animation_BB-8_robot_holding_a_chart_containing_a_53875512-7623-4931-9d91-11764eb364f8_0.jpg?alt=media&token=ea2c8a40-4adf-48f1-89f3-4fe82d738724")
                        .build()
                )
                .putCustomData("image-url", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jinarya-315507.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2Fzitykach_3d_animation_BB-8_robot_holding_a_chart_containing_a_53875512-7623-4931-9d91-11764eb364f8_0.jpg?alt=media&token=ea2c8a40-4adf-48f1-89f3-4fe82d738724")
                .build()
        )

The issue I am facing here is that the images are not getting attached to the notification before showing it at the client(I am testing on a Real Device), otherwise everything else works fine.
The NotificationService class doesnt seem to be triggered at all since the print statements dont show up in the console.
